# How to use react-native-encrypted-storage with redux-persist

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm currently trying to use this react-native-encrypted-storage with redux-persist for Persisting in a secure storage, below is my code

store.ts

```
import {combineReducers, configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import persistedReducer from './persistedSlice';
import {
  FLUSH,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
  REHYDRATE,
  persistReducer,
  persistStore,
} from 'redux-persist';
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage';
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  persisted: persistedReducer,
});

const persistedCombinedReducer = persistReducer(
  {
    key: 'root',
    storage: EncryptedStorage,
    whitelist: ['persisted'],
  },
  combinedReducer,
);

const createStores = () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedCombinedReducer,
    middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
      getDefaultMiddleware({
        serializableCheck: {
          ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
        },
      }),
  });

  const persistedStore = persistStore(store);

  return {store, persistedStore};
};

const {store, persistedStore} = createStores();

export {store, persistedStore};

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

type DispatchFunc = () => AppDispatch;
export const useAppDispatch: DispatchFunc = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

persistedSlice.ts

```
import {PayloadAction, createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

interface PersistedState {
  user?: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  };
  token?: string;
}

const initialState: PersistedState = {};

const persistedSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'persisted',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setPersistedData(state, action: PayloadAction<PersistedState>) {
      console.log('AAAA: ', {
        state,
        data: action.payload,
      });
      state = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {setPersistedData} = persistedSlice.actions;

export default persistedSlice.reducer;
```

When I called setPersistedData from useAppDispatch, the setPersistedData function is called. However, the state was not updated. (The state was not updated)

The implementation in my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useAppDispatch, useAppSelector} from './store';
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {setPersistedData} from './persistedSlice';

const Consumer = () => {
  const user = useAppSelector(state => state.persisted.user);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>User info: {user ? JSON.stringify(user) : 'unknown'}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Set user"
        onPress={() => {
          dispatch(
            setPersistedData({
              user: {
                id: '1',
                name: 'Mister A',
              },
              token: 'abcA@@',
            }),
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Consumer;
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a state persistence issue, or an updating the store issue? Please [edit] to clarify in more specific details what the exact issue or problem is.

Comment: @DrewReese I have issue with store update and persistance. When I run dispatch(setPersistedData(value)), the setPersistedData function inside the store is called but the state was not updated

Comment: How are you verifying/validating the state update?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added my implementation for the code I'm using.